# same thumbnail for two different products having different attributes(id,sku,price, stock level)

Tags: magento-1.7, product, attributes, category, product-attribute

I am developing online apparel store. our store has only two type products with different ID, price stock level and other attributes but we want the same thumbnail for both products and it does not repeat in store as thumbnail please tell any solution for this because I am new in Magento.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, do you want to assign same thumbnail image to two products, if yes then, what is the issue in that?

Comment: issue is repetition of same thumbnail in store

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a grouped product.

A grouped product is an "abstract" product, in the way that you don't actually sell it as it doesn't exist.

Say you are selling boxes :

- Box A : 60x60x60 | stock : 30 | sku : boxa | type_id : simple
- Box B : 70x60x70 | stock : 15 | sku : boxb | type_id : simple

What you'll need to "gather" those 2 products is a grouped product

- Box :  no dimensions | stock : none | sku : box_g | type_id : grouped

It seems to be the easiest way to do it for me.

Comment: thanks for your answer julien but here scenario different let me explain it in simple example , you want a new shirt. you visit my store and you like any article now we gives you freedom that you buy a ready to wear or you buy fabric of same article and later on stitched it from your tailor, now if u select ready to wear then your select your size, if you select stitch-able fabric then just no need to mention size and because we have same article for both product we want to show ready to wear image in thumbnails so this more clear

Comment: so it's basically a t-shirt that would have 2 options? ready to wear and stitchable? and then once you select "ready to wear" you'd have to choose the size?

Comment: yes exactly please help me because am new to magneto

Comment: you could use configurable product. Except it won't fit your requirements, because in order to chose a size for your product, you need to have separate simple products with different sizes.

Comment: https://www.motifz.com.pk/store/index.php?main_page=page_2&keyword=MWU00757- that was our current system this was develop in zencart even this has the functionality to select from any two options and with selection the product Id, model and price change but we some issues that's why we want to change

Comment: is there any extension through which we achieve this functionality free or paid please mention

Comment: I have no clue sorry.

Comment: is there any other magneto help or support plate-forum? please suggest me